# Raise Http404 in url pattern

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm trying to override a url in django-profiles to raise a 404 instead of passing to the view.

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
url(r'^profiles/$', lamdba x: raise Http404)
```

But the above doesn't work. Is this sort of thing possible?

I know I can write a new view that raises a 404, but I'd rather not if I can do it in the url pattern directly.

**edit:** Specifically, I get `invalid syntax (urls.py, line 29)` with the above example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the view [`django.views.defaults.page_not_found`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view).

Answer (score 14):

Starting from [Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view), the `page_not_found` view now "accepts a second parameter, the exception that triggered the error." So the solution proposed above by Christoffer requires some minor change:

```
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^profiles/$', page_not_found, {'exception': Exception('Not Found')}),
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your solution could be improved using `django.http.Http404` exception instead of a generic `Exception`

Comment: That would be something like that:
`from django.http.response import Http404`

`url(r'^profiles/$', page_not_found, {'exception': Http404()}),`

Answer (score 2):

A working example..

In your urls.py add:

```
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^profiles/$', page_not_found),
)
```